# range response have difference with range request when last range have empty value

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

i try get data from google sheet using  method `spreadsheets.values.get`.

sheet tabel

| 1 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | One | Two | Three |
| 3 | One | Two |  |
| 4 | One | Two | Three |

the problem is when making a request like : `'range' => 'A2:C'`, return value data on range 3 only give values `['one', 'two']` not `['one', 'two', '']`.

Any solution or references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the values are retrieved with `spreadsheets.values.get`, your situation is obtained as the default situation. In your sample Spreadsheet, it becomes `[["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two"],["One","Two","Three"]]`. So in this case, it is required to prepare a script for achieving your goal. In this answer, I would like to propose the script.

#### Sample script:

```php
// Use spreadsheets.values.get. Please replace this for your actual script.
$res = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);

// I added below script.
$values = $res['values'];
$maxLen = max(array_map('count', $values));
foreach ($values as $i => $v) {
    $len = count($v);
    if ($len < $maxLen) {
        $values[$i] = array_merge($v, array_fill(0, $maxLen - $len, ''));
    }
}
```

- In this modification, `""` is added for the row when the length of the row is less than the maximum length of the array.
- When your sample values are used, in this modification, `$values` retrieved by `$service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range)`, it's `[["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two"],["One","Two","Three"]]`. And, when my additional script is used, `$values` becomes `[["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two",""],["One","Two","Three"]]`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)